# Replacing elements inside brackets in an expression with the values of those elements in python

Tags: python, regex

So, I am having an expression like - "{alpha}+{beta}+{gamma}" and a dictionary having the corresponding values of the terms that are enclosed within '{' and '}' brackets('alpha', 'beta' and 'gamma') like:-
dictionary_with_values = {
        "alpha": "APLHA_@*09",
        "beta": "BETA*$$*01,
        "gamma": "GAMMA**%_10,
}.
How do I go around replacing the values of the terms enclosed within '{' and '}' brackets with their corresponding values present in the dictionary given above?

I was trying to do this using regex in python but all I have achieved till now is extracting the terms enclosed within brackets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dictionary- or keyword-unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) here:

```
s = "{alpha}+{beta}+{gamma}"
d = { "alpha": "APLHA_@09", "beta": "BETA$$01", "gamma": "GAMMA*%_10" }
print(s.format(**d))
```

Result:

```
In [31]: print(s.format(**d))
APLHA_@09+BETA$$01+GAMMA*%_10
```